# MVC report with rdlc dataset error GetValidationErros

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, dataset, rdlc

I'm making report with rdlc in asp.net mvc4.Dataset getting error `GetValidationErrors` at Avaliable datasets.

how can I access my class ?

Comment: any idea for my project

Comment: why no comment, no answer!